# Can $\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{l-1} h^i (\prod_{j=i+1}^{l-1} a_{x_j}) (b_{x_i}-x_{i+1})} {h^l-\prod_{i=0}^{l-1}a_{x_i}}$ have an infinite number of solutions?

Tags: number-theory

Is it possible to have $h>1$ in $\mathbb{N}$ and two integer collections $(a_i) \in \mathbb{Z}^h$ and $(b_i) \in \mathbb{Z}^h$ where $\forall i, gcd(a_i,h)=1$ such that there is an infinite number of collections of integers $(x_i)$ so that:

$\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{l-1} h^i (\prod_{j=i+1}^{l-1} a_{x_j}) (b_{x_i}-x_{i+1})} {h^l - \displaystyle \prod_{i=0}^{l-1}a_{x_i}} $

is an integer? ($l$ being the length of $(x_i)$, and assuming $x_0=x_l$)

I know that for some specific choices of $(a_i)$ and $(b_i)$, it is very hard to know how many solutions there are (for example: $a=(1,3)$, $b=(0,2)$), and for some other choices it can be proven that there is only a finite number of solutions (like if $a=(1,1)$ and $b=(0,0)$), but I wonder if anybody has ever found specific $(a_i)$ and $(b_i)$ where we can find an infinite number of solutions.